# Problem with minecraft eye rig

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to make a minecraft eye rig, but I'm having problems. The pupils should stay inside the eye and move within the limits and they should follow the head bone. Does anyone know how to create a control panel that works?

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Your pupils are not parented to anything for the moment, what did you plan exactly?

Comment: in another version of the file I not this, (if you want I can share it )i have parented the eye bone and used the bone constraint "limit location", to make the pupil move inside the eye, but there is a problem when I tilt the head bone the piupli follow in
a strange way

Comment: is there a reason why you don't join the pupil to the body mesh? If you want to keep them apart, select a pupil, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select a bone, press Ctrl P (Parent to) > Bone

Comment: can I show you the other file. I'm new to blender and I'm not thet good with english

Comment: please share it with blend exchange as well

Comment: From what I see the problem is that your pupil bone, called Bone, is not parented to the good bone, you need to parent it to the bone called TopM.L (which is the head bone)

Comment: I already try it, it doesen't follow well when I bend the head

Comment: it must be because of the Limit Location constraint, switch it to Local Space instead of World Space

Comment: I olso tried that

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but why on earth does your rig have 800k triangles? I know you don't want to keep the full cubic Minecraft aspect and have some flexibility in the mouth shapes and whatnot, but you should add your geometry where it's needed, not everywhere. That's just overkill and your viewport performances shows it very well: I can't even rotate the head without a massive fps drop with a high end computer.

Comment: I have donwloaded blender 2 weeks ago i'm still learning :(

Answer (score 0):

In *Edit* mode, parent *Bone* to *TopM.L*. In *Pose* mode, switch the *Limit Location* constraint of *Bone* from *World Space* to *Local Space*. Redefine the *Minimum* and *Maximum* values on XYZ so that it's correctly set. It should work:

[image]

Keep in mind that XYZ are now the axis of the bone itself, activate the bone axis display to make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: when I try swith from world space to local space, I have problem with fizing the XYZ. the pupil doesn't move on the axes

Comment: It's like the axes are messed up, it move wird

Comment: please share your last version

Comment: when I change the the value of the axis Z it move the piupil on another axis

Comment: First thing, bring back all the min and max values to 0. Then set the min and max you want, but again, keep in mind that these are the XYZ values of the bone itself: In the Object Data panel, display the axis, see my edit. For Z choose a low value like Min Z > -0.1, and Max Z > 0

Comment: I changed the axis values ​​but the pupil does not move

Comment: As I said, set Min Z > -0.1, and Max Z > 0

Comment: okey the z work now, but i don't know what value use with x

Comment: hey you need to find a bit by yourself  ;)

Comment: but I am trying sorry if I'm making you angry. I did not mean

Comment: I'm not angry, it's just that now you have everything to go on   ;)

Comment: okay thanks, i really appreciate what you did for me